# Custom player using NDK/C++/MediaCodec - starvation/buffering in decoder

Tags: android-ndk, codec, android-mediacodec, qualcomm

I have a very interesting problem.

I am running custom movie player based on NDK/C++/CMake toolchain that opens streaming URL (mp4, H.264 & stereo audio). In order to restart from given position, player opens stream, buffers frames to some length and then seeks to new position and start decoding and playing. This works fine all the times except if we power-cycle the device and follow the same steps.

This was reproduced on few version of the software (plugin build against android-22..26) and hardware (LG G6, G5 and LeEco). This issue does not happen if you keep app open for 10 mins.

I am looking for possible areas of concern. I have played with decode logic (it is based on the approach described as synchronous processing using buffers).

> **Edit - More Information (4/23)**

I modified player to pick a stream and then played only video instead of video+audio. This resulted in constant starvation resulting in buffering. This appears to have changed across android version (no fix data here). I do believe that I am running into decoder starvation. Previously, I had set timeouts of 0 for both `AMediaCodec_dequeueInputBuffer` and `AMediaCodec_dequeueOutputBuffer`, which I changed on input side to 1000 and 10000 but does not make much difference.

My player is based on NDK/C++ interface to MediaCodec, CMake build passes `-DANDROID_ABI="armeabi-v7a with NEON"` and `-DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL="android-22" \` and C++_static.

Anyone can share what timeouts they have used and found success with it or anything that would help avoid starvation or resulting buffering?

Answer (score 0):

This is solved for now. Starvation was not caused from decoding perspective but images were consumed in faster pace as clock value returned were not in sync. I was using `clock_gettime` method with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` clock id, which is recommended way but it was always faster for first 5-10 mins of restarting device. This device only had Wi-Fi connection. Changing clock id to `CLOCK_REALTIME` ensures correct presentation of images and no starvation.